# Problem displaying charts in clone of open.fda.gov

Tags: openfda

I have cloned the open.fda.gov repository and followed instructions to get the site running on my machine.  I've been meticulous to install all the ruby and nodejs dependencies, however when jekyll is serving my site, I am not able to see any of the charts. For example, http://localhost:4000/drug/event/ does not show the chart as is displayed on https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/ .

How can I get my local site to display the charts?

Comment: this sounds more like a question for stack overflow

Comment: Are you willing to open up your server to remote access so we can help troubleshoot? If not, how about a screenshot at least?